# width auto problems for an element containing floated children

Tags: html, css

This weird behavior is driving me crazy.
If I upload the page on the server, the first time I open it on *chrome/safari* I get this problem:

[image]

If i refresh it, or when I'm working on the page locally, no problems at all.

[image]

The *nav* simply doesn't expand its *width: auto* to fit all *a* floated elements.

This is the really simple code (I deleted not-related rules, but if it could be useful to know I'm using a webfont):

**html:**

```
<nav>
  <a href="#">button</a>
  <a href="#">button</a>
  <a href="#">button</a>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</nav>
```

**css:**

```
nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -17px;
  width: auto;
  height: 33px;
}

nav > a {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  padding: 11px 13px;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #7a7e7f;
}

div.clear {
  clear: both;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle replicating this problem, or a link to some other kind of live demo?

Comment: change this display: block; to display: inline-block;

Comment: Please provide a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) that replicates the issue.

Comment: I've had webfonts cause issues with this exact situation. That could very well be the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically setting the width of the nav element to 100% does the trick. Here’s an optimized example:

**HTML**

```
<nav>
  <a href="#">button</a>
  <a href="#">button</a>
  <a href="#">button</a>
</nav>
```

**CSS**

```
nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -17px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden; /* Makes the clearing div obsolete */
}

nav > a {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
  padding: 11px 13px;
  border: 1px solid #7a7e7f;
}
```

Check it out on Codepen: http://codepen.io/zitrusfrisch/pen/Jcirx